# Chrome distrusted in M70 for Aliexpress

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension

We use to fetch product details from Aliexpress for our drop shipping store, but with the latest version of chrome V66(64bit) we see a message in console;

```
The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://us.ynuf.alipay.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
```

Since upgrading Chrome we are unable to fetch product details and it seems like the distrusting SSL is the cause of this. I have zero knowledge about this matter but i am sure you guys can shed some light on it.

The extension we are using is [Opencart AliExpress Importer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/opencart-aliexpress-impor/oacipfkfeiojbgojbnnkdfelggfjigla) and it was working fine till last week. now we see the following errors and warnings.

```
jewelry-sets-more.html?spm=2114.10010108.100004.4.537649a9Fi8HYy:1 The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://us.ynuf.alipay.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

aksb.min.js:22 [Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use standardized API: Paint Timing. https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5637885046816768.

// ERROR
jquery.min.js:4 GET https://supply.mentorarts.com/index.php?route=product/warehouse_product/getProductTotalReviews&callback=jQuery32101105891334556186_1524054639658&review_url=%2F%2Ffeedback.aliexpress.com%2Fdisplay%2FproductEvaluation.htm%3FproductId%3D32610636905%26ownerMemberId%3D112726712%26companyId%3D102900045%26memberType%3Dseller%26startValidDate%3D%26i18n%3Dtrue&_=1524054639757 404 (Not Found)
```

We have 2 stores hosted on different servers and we made no code or dashboard changes. but after the recent update of chrome all seems to not working.

Comment: The error says it all. Remind aliexpress to update their certificates.

Comment: @wOxxOm do we have to update the SSL of our store as well? I am confused that if thats the case it has been days why aliexpress is not updating their ssl?

Comment: Actually, this should not affect you in Chrome 66. Apparently something else is causing the problem. Try debugging your code, check devtools network log or your server log.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is just a warning (I see it in my app with paypal too) which clearly indicates that certificate **will** be distrusted  starting from Chrome 70

Comment: @wOxxOm  will copy the errors in my question now

Comment: @Glapa I am confused since that warning says "Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources." if that has anything to do with the extension to fetch product data

Comment: @wOxxOm I added some more details to the question. can you find the cause of this please?

Comment: The last URL is weird: `https://supply.mentorarts.com//index.php` - it has `//` after the host name (usually it's always `/`).

Comment: @wOxxOm yes and perhaps that is the root cause but why it happened when we made no changes? its happening with all our stores on different servers. is it the chrome or the extension malfunctioned after the upgrade

Comment: @wOxxOm  the `//` was due to the URL we provided has `.com/` so the `//` is fixed but the issue is still there. `https://supply.mentorarts.com/index.php?route=product/warehouse_product/getProductTotalReviews&callback=jQuery32107447133152461956_1524055992383&review_url=%2F%2Ffeedback.aliexpress.com%2Fdisplay%2FproductEvaluation.htm%3FproductId%3D32646801912%26ownerMemberId%3D117348198%26companyId%3D107286264%26memberType%3Dseller%26startValidDate%3D%26i18n%3Dtrue&_=1524055992412`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Google security blog](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html):

> Starting with Chrome 66, Chrome will remove trust in Symantec-issued certificates issued prior to June 1, 2016.

Comment: am i facing the issue due to SSL? sorry for being lame but i have no knowledge in this